# Quadratic equation calculator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, calculator, c-strings

I am creating a MFC dialog based quadratic equation solving calculator.It works except when the discriminant is less than zero case.
Her's my code for `delta(discriminant)<0` situation:

```
delta=-1*delta;
    root1=-b/(2.0*a);   
    root2=sqrt(delta)/(2.0*a);  

}
CString result1,result2;
result1.Format(_T("%g"),root1);
result2.Format(_T("%g"),root2);
if(delta<0){
    CString r1=result1+_T("+ i ")+result2;
    CString r2=result1+_T("- i ")+result2;
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT4,r1);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT4,r2);
}
```

If I input a=1,b=1,c=1 what I get printed in `IDC_EDit4` is `-0.5` and in `IDC_EDIT5` `0.866025`.
Where as I want to print in `IDC_EDIT4` `-0.5+i0.866025`
and in `IDC_EDIT5`is `-0.5-i 0.8660.25`.
Concatenation of CStings is not performed correctly I think.How can I change this please?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use std::complex instead of this concatenation madness : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/

Comment: You have negated `delta` before you check it for `< 0`. The code you show doesn't actually run (as you could have easily confirmed yourself, with a little help from the debugger).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Realized it now.Thanks